# Convert String to Hex using ethers.js

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, encoding, decoding, hex

If I use `web3.js` I can convert a string to hex with:

```
web3.utils.toHex('4c7b7ffb66b344fbaa64995af81e355a')
```

How do I use the same utility for `ethers.js`?

Comment: I don't get it, `4c7b7ffb66b344fbaa64995af81e355a` is **already** in hex format!

Comment: Besides that, a simple search on their official documentation page gives [this](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/search/?search=hex).

Comment: You need the 0x

Comment: Is that for real??? Just add `"0x"` at the beginning of the string then!

Comment: My input varies, so just in case whatever input isn't already hexlified I want to make sure it always hexlifies. In this case yes, I could just append the `0x`, plus, it makes my code more readable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I couldn't find it in their old documentation but if you check their legacy documentation https://docs.ethers.io/v4/api-utils.html#hex-strings you will find that you can convert any number, BigNumber, hex string or arrayish to hex with the following command:

`ethers.utils.hexlify(5)` which returns `0x05`

Hope this solves your question.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/96892/61070 answers the original question (string to hex)

Answer (score 5):

Just as an addition, if someone is searching how to convert a non number string to hex, ethers can handle this as well:

```
ethers.utils.hexlify(ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes('<YOUR_STRING>'));
```