# String to Hex in Ethers.js

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, string, typescript, encoding

Only one question: How can I convert string to hex in **ethers.js**

I need some alternative to
`web3.utils.utf8ToHex()` in ethers.

Comment: What does the string look like? Is it something like `"0x123beef"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find such a function in ethers.js (`hexlify` doesn't accept strings as input), but maybe you'll find [this `utf8ToHex` helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61210686/6660476)  useful:

```js
function utf8ToHex(str) {
  return '0x' + Array.from(str).map(c =>
    c.charCodeAt(0) < 128 ? c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) :
    encodeURIComponent(c).replace(/\%/g,'').toLowerCase()
  ).join('');
}

const string = 'test';
const hexString = utf8ToHex(string);
const web3HexString = web3.utils.utf8ToHex(string);
console.log(hexString, web3HexString);
```

Answer (score 15):

Good news! Ethers can natively read strings like `"0x123beef"` as a datatype it calls a `HexString` ([source](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bytes/#HexString))

Once you have a `HexString`, the docs for the available functions/methods are [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bytes/#byte-manipulation--hexstring-manipulation).

**Update**: This answer assumes the goal is to go from a hex value that is encoded as a string, like `"0x123beef"`. If you have an arbitrary string (eg `"yo wassup"`), you would first need to convert it into utf-8 array, and then make it into a hex:

```js
ethers.utils.hexlify(ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes("yo wassup"));
// output: 0x796f20776173737570
```

Comment: The question is how to go from a string like "sif" to a hex string like 0x736966 though.

Comment: @JamesMoore We'd assumed the intent was for values like `"0x123beef"`, but have updated the answer to include arbitrary strings too!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `formatBytes32String`.

```
ethers.utils.formatBytes32String("YOUR_STRING")
```